# Passing keyword arguments with a hyphen

Tags: python, keyword-argument, hyphenation

I have a keyword argument function:

```py
def f1(**kw):
    for key,val in kw.iteritems():
        print "key=%s val=%s" % (key,val)

f1(Attr1 = "Val1", Attr2 = "Val2")  # works fine.

f1(Attr1-SubAttr = "Val1", Attr2 = "Val2")  # complains about keyword being an expression.

f1("Attr1-SubAttr" = "Val1", Attr2 = "Val2")  # doesn't work either.
```

How do I pass in keywords with a hyphen?  I don't have control over these keywords since I am parsing these from an existing legacy database.

Comment: You can't have keywords with a hyphen.

Comment: is good idea version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956364/function-accepts-keyword-arguments-that-are-not-identifiers

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Keyword arguments *must* be [valid Python identifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers); these don't allow for `-` as that's reserved for subtraction.

You can pass in arbitrary strings using the [`**kwargs` variable keyword argument syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) instead:

```
f1(**{"Attr1-SubAttr": "Val1", "Attr2": "Val2"})
```

Comment: Just leaving a note: used this on Python Zeep, to pass a SOAP <choice> that had a name with dash.

Answer (score 0):

To make the above code to work in python 3 `iteritems()` replaced by `items()`.