# Keyword varargs with invalid variable names

Tags: python, variadic-functions

We all know python's varargs feature:

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)

f(1, 2, foo='bar') # output: (1, 2) {'foo': 'bar'}

kwargs= {'a': None}
f(**kwargs) # output: () {'a': None}
```

But I recently discovered that it's possible to use strings that aren't valid variable names as keys, like so:

```
kwargs= {'name with spaces': None, '%^+': None}
f(**kwargs) # output: () {'name with spaces': None, '%^+': None}
```

But it's not like there's no error checking happening, for example if you try

```
f(**{1: None})
```

you'll get `TypeError: f() keywords must be strings`.

So now I'm wondering if this is really valid python or maybe just a CPython implementation detail? I haven't been able to find details about this behaviour in the docs.

Comment: I was writing response while suddenly your question has been closed, so here is my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956364/function-accepts-keyword-arguments-that-are-not-identifiers/39363530#39363530