# **kwargs parameter name has a "." in it creating an error

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am trying to pass an argument into a function with **kwargs
allas some of the argument names contain a . and I get an error as code editor expect argument name and don't recognize it, likely because of the "."

```
def get_active_offers(**kwargs):
    params = {}
    for args in kwargs:
        params[args]=kwargs.values() 
    response = api_request(params)
    return response


test = get_active_offers(BasicFilters.PriceFrom="1")
```

is there a way around it (something like an f string for arguments?)

for the moment my solution has been to pass the name of the argument and the value as a list and naming it with a simpler name but I am trying to learn the proper way?

```
def get_active_offers(**kwargs):
    params = {}
    for args in kwargs.values():
        params[args[0]]=args[1] 
    response = api_request(params)
    return response


test = get_active_offers(argument = ["BasicFilters.PriceFrom","1"])
```

Comment: Keyword arguments are, as the name says, *arguments* – i.e. pairs of *identifier* and value. ``BasicFilters.PriceFrom`` isn't an identifier. Can you change ``get_active_offers `` to not use ``**kwargs``? Why don't you pass this key-value data as a dict?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you it makes sense to pass it as one dict and add it to the existing dict with the other arguments already within the function (I had simplified it for readability)

Comment: Note that `kwargs` is already a dictionary, so your loop to convert it to dictionary is useless.

Comment: @mozway indeed but I simplified the function for readability and in reality, I am doing more with the kwargs within the function.

Comment: Related: [Is is safe to use a function accepts kwargs keyword arguments that are not identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956364/is-is-safe-to-use-a-function-accepts-kwargs-keyword-arguments-that-are-not-ident)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the comments said, you can pass the argument as a dict:

```
def get_active_offers(**kwargs):
    params = {}
    for args in kwargs:
        params[args]=kwargs.values() 
    response = api_request(params)
    return response


test = get_active_offers(**{"BasicFilters.PriceFrom":"1"})
```

The above syntax of using `**` with the argument is called "dictionary unpacking"

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that if ``get_active_offers`` accepts non-identifiers and calling it passes non-identifiers, it's easier and faster to drop the un/packing ``**`` on both sides. That also avoids the worry whether it's valid to have non-identifier argument identifiers.